# How to open list on hover of individual li element and only collapse on mouseout of ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a collapsible menu with stucture like:

- Parent
- Parent 2
- Parent 3

  - Sub category

I have the following javascript

```
    var config = {
        over: function() { $(this).children('ul').slideDown('slow'); },
        timeout: 5,
        out: function() { }
    }

    $("ul.root-tags li").hoverIntent(config);

    $('ul.root-tags').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).children('li ul').each(function () {
            $(this).slideUp('slow');
        });
    });
```

Basically I want to open sub categories on hover of the parent item but only collapse opened subcategories on mouseout of the entire list, not just the parent item. My current code does not do this. What changes do I need to make?

jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/zkhVC/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should address what you are asking for:

```
$('#head').mouseleave(function() {

    $(this).find('li ul').each(function () {
        $(this).stop().slideUp('slow');
    });

});

$("ul li").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown('slow');
});​
```

**Fiddle**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zkhVC/9/)

**Explanation**

- Do not use `hover` event, because it will get fired over and over again you are over the element. You want to use `mouseenter` instead.
- Use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`:

> The `mouseleave`event differs from `mouseout`in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If `mouseout` were used in this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The `mouseleave`event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

- Take a deeper look at how selectors works: you do not need of the `children` function here.
- You want to use the `stop` function before calling an animation to prevent animations buffering.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a little strange, but maybe we could explain it like this :

It seems that mouseout () event is send to children of ul.root-tags. So you should try the event.stopPropagation() method avoid [bubbling down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728252/jquery-stoppropagation-bubble-down).

```
$('ul.root-tags').mouseout(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('li ul').each(function () {
        $(this).slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

If it doesn't work right now, using e.target, you may find exactly who calls who.

Comment: Modified the jsfiddle with the solution of Nicolas Zozol works:
http://jsfiddle.net/zkhVC/5/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`:

```
$('ul.root-tags').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideUp('slow');
});

$("ul.root-tags li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown('slow');
})​
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KLKq2/).

Comment: Form mkyong : both mouseout() and mouseleave() events are fire when the mouse leaves the matched element. The only different is in the way of the “event bubbling”
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/