# Clicking on label doesn't trigger click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<label><input type="checkbox">True?</label>
```

and

```
$("label").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

When I click the checkbox class toggles, when I click "True?" nothing happens. Why?

Then if I don't wrap checkbox in label everything works fine.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1"><label for="c1">True?</label>
```

This is so weird... And it doesn't matter if I put "for" or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/zufs6ueh/1/

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Does the `onclick` fire twice? `label` interacts with `input` in a specific way.

Comment: not sure why, I think the label's click event might be reassigned to the input when it's contained in the label or something like that, but a solution to it could be to bind the event to the input and change the parent's label like `$("label input").click(function () {
 $(this).parent('label').toggleClass("active");
});`

Comment: @Halcyon Yes, it seems that  onclick fires twice, because I see empty "class" in web inspector. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would be safer to use:

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('change', function (v) {

        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        }
    });

});
```

Using `change` instead of `click` allows for people that navigate forms using the keyboard.

Comment: Your answer is good by suggesting to bind event on the input, and not on all labels. Anyway, if you mean use spacebar to check the checkbox when you say *"allows for people that navigate forms using the keyboard"*, it think there is no problem at all since the spacebar triggers the `click` as well. +1

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown thanks, I did not know the spacebar triggers `click`. You learn something every day! But yes you're right, the main issue here is attaching the event to the checkbox as opposed to the label.

Comment: Ok, this works fine, but I still need to know what is wrong with my original example.

Comment: @Andrey as has been mentioned before, when clicking the label the 'click' event is firing twice. You can add `evt.stopPropagation(); evt.preventDefault();` to the end of the `click` function to prevent this. (And `evt` as the argument of the function)

Comment: @rwacarter, yes but why is it firing twice? Isn't it weired? Maybe it's a bug? ;-)

Comment: @Andrey it's to do with the union between a label and an input within it. A similar question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185265/jquery-click-event-triggers-twice-when-clicked-on-html-label

Comment: This is awesome :) thak

Comment: Is simple: Label process the event, then passes it down int children - the input.

Answer (score 2):

Clicking the label also triggers a click on the input so bind the change event to the checkbox itself:

```js
$(function(){
    $("label input").on("click",function(){
 $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.active {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" />True?</label>
```

#### Or With CSS 3

If you don't need to support old browsers, you could use the `:checked` pseudo-class in CSS instead:

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {color:red;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="demo" name="demo"> 
<label for="demo">True?</label>
```

Comment: I'm always a fan of avoiding javascript when unnecessary, but just a heads up that the `:checked` pseudo class won't work in IE<9

Comment: @rwacarter - Agreed. Annoying isn't it? Ideally you'd test for support then use a JS fallback.

Comment: @Moob, your code does the same thing @rwacarter suggested, but still it's not clear why `onclick` fires twice...
As for JS I need it to do other things after the label is clicked, so can't avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You're really close @Andrey, some noteworthy things about HTML *`input`s*;

- Both `radio` and `checkbox` HTML *`type`s* can have an `onclick` call out to JavaScript
- Both `radio` and `checkbox` HTML *`type`s* have the `.checked` property that maybe inspected by JavaScript and the `:checked` pseudo class within CSS
- Using *`name`s* on `radio` HTML *`type`s* allows for *grouping* things

Here's some example code that does *stuff* with a `checkbox`...

```js
/**
 * Example JavaScript function for HTML input radio or checkbox types to call
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function checkCheckbox(checkbox) {
  if (checkbox.checked != true) return false;
  /* Do JavaSript things when checkbox is checked */
  console.log('checkbox.checked -> ' + checkbox.checked);
  window.alert('checkbox.value -> ' + checkbox.value);
  return true;
}
```

```css
/**
 * Hide things that should not be seen by just anyone
 */
.menu__checkbox,
.menu__container {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* Old MS compatibility */
}

/**
 * Stylize the label some
 */
.menu__label {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}


/**
 * Show some things when checkbox is checked
 * Note, if feeling adventurous try using a `~` instead of `+`
 */
.menu__checkbox:checked + .menu > .menu__container {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

/**
 * Oh and un-rotate label when checkbox is checked too
 */
.menu__checkbox:checked + .menu > .menu__label {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"
       class="menu__checkbox"
       value="valuable_checkbox"
       onclick="checkCheckbox(this);"
       id="trigger-menu">


<div class="menu">

  <div class="menu__container">
    <p class="menu__description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>

  <label for="trigger-menu"
         class="menu__label">
         &#x25B2;
  </label>

</div>
```

... if ya look real close, *targeting* via `trigger-menu` shared between the above *`label`'s* `for` and the *`input`'s* `id` is doing some things with CSS and HTML that many might resort to JavaScript to do... though placing the checkbox so far outside of the menu's scope was only for demonstration; just 'cause something *can* be done doesn't always mean *should* in other words.

Like I eluded to the question's code was really close...

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="c1"><label for="c1">True?</label>
```

... probably would be functional with...

```html
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" onclick="window.alert('this.checked -> ' + this.checked);">
<label for="c1">Is checked?</label>
```

And as I also hinted that `radio` *`type`d* *`input`s* could be use similarly, the following is a preview of something that may be made public one day within something ridiculous...

```html
    <div class="menu__style">
      <input type="radio"
             name="colorize"
             value="Default"
             onclick="color_picker.unsetAlternateStyleSheet()"
             class="menu__style__item"
             id="style-default">
      <label for="style-default"
             class="menu__style__label">Default Style</label>
      <br>

      <input type="radio"
             name="colorize"
             value="AlternateStyleOne"
             onclick="color_picker.setAlternateStyleSheet(title = this.value)"
             class="menu__style__item"
             id="style-one">
      <label for="style-one"
             class="menu__style__label">First Alternative Style</label>
      <br>

      <input type="radio"
             name="colorize"
             value="AlternateStyleTwo"
             onclick="color_picker.setAlternateStyleSheet(title = this.value)"
             class="menu__style__item"
             id="style-two">
      <label for="style-two"
             class="menu__style__label">Second Alternative Style</label>
    </div>
```