# Jquery: how to prevent running multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for my English, I'm not native English speaker.

I have problem with my code. I have on page something like this:

```js
$('#hook label').on('click', function() {
    console.log('ok');
    icon = $(this).next('input').val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hook">
    <label><input> <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" ></label>
    <label><input> <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" ></label>
    <label><input> <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" ></label>
    <label><input> <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" ></label>
</div>
```

And this code is running twice if I click on image, but only one when I click on input or label element. How can I prevent to running this twice?

Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/00akgoe7/2/

Comment: Are the images overlapping?

Comment: No. Labels are blocks, images are in block.

Comment: Side note: I do not think `next` is the right method in that code. Shouldn't it be `find`

Comment: @epascarello, this code is not bad. This is only to retrieve value from input element, and this is not reason for running twice.
OK, I will change this to find.

Comment: `$(this)` is the label that is cicked and `next()` looks at the next sibling which would be a label.  The inputs are not siblings, they are children.

Comment: @epascarello, OK, this is changed by now to `find`, but this isn't main problem.

Comment: can you you use `one` instead of `on`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery click event triggers twice when clicked on html label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185265/jquery-click-event-triggers-twice-when-clicked-on-html-label)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the default behavior of label. To stop that, you need to tell to the event object to stop is default behavior like this:

```
$('#hook label').on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log('ok');
    icon = $(this).next('input').val();
});
```

Clicking on a label associeted with the `for` attribute or inside the label, focus the input with a "fake" click event. This is why you get the event twice since by extension, if you click the input, you click the label (the parent) also.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Here's a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185265/jquery-click-event-triggers-twice-when-clicked-on-html-label

Comment: While this is the solution I think an explanation of how exactly this happens would be good too. Inputs inside labels receive `click` events from the label parent too.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv apparently, label is in union with input but I would like to see some resource explaining this as well.

Comment: I edit my response to be more precise about this behavior. Thanks for the proposition.

Comment: This works, however it prevents the radio button from being selected

Comment: Thanks! This works.
@krato, solution for it is
`if(ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'label' || ev.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') return;`

Answer (score 1):

It's two times because when you click on the **label** it send a click event also to the **input** and the new event bubbles back to the **label**. It's tricky :)

It's in all browsers for a better form usability.

So the another possible solution is:

```
$('label').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "LABEL") {
        alert("!! here")
    }
});
```

Try it live: http://jsfiddle.net/8qffhwm3/2/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a preventDefault().

```
$('#hook label').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('ok');
});
```

I expect that it help you.

Answer (score -2):

If you want prevent from the event being fired twice, you can use the 'mousedown' event handler. It will just be triggered once, as it is not triggered by standard by clicking the label.

Comment: The answer provided by @Swatto shows you how NOT complex the code is. Why use _hacks_ if you can do it just right by preventing the default behavior.

Comment: The preventDefault will also prevent the box from being checked, if that is desired, of course, do it like that

Comment: mouse down can confuse user, in this case mouse up is better but it's still kind of hacking