# Applying if and else condition to add and remove class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created the below code where I want to create an if/else condition where when the user clicks on the label, a class would be added and when unclicks, that class would be removed. I am stuck-up applying the same.

My code as below.

**LIVE FIDDLE LINK**

**[Complete working code here](https://jsfiddle.net/zdwjnLvL/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="customCheckboxBtns">
<div class="ck-button"><label><input checked="checked" name="column-2" type="checkbox">1</label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="selected"><input checked="checked" name="column-3" type="checkbox">2</label></div><!-- This is how it will be added dynamically -->
<div class="ck-button"><label><input checked="checked" name="column-4" type="checkbox">3</label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label><input checked="checked" name="column-5" type="checkbox">4</label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label><input checked="checked" name="column-6" type="checkbox">5</label></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.customCheckboxBtns{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.25rem;
    overflow:auto;
}

.ck-button {
    margin-right: 0.375rem;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #26a69a;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    color:#999999;
}

.ck-button:hover {
    background:#7dcac2;
    border:1px solid #26a69a;
    color:#26a69a;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.ck-button label {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    display:block;
    background:#26a69a;
    color:#ffffff;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.ck-button label:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.ck-button input:checked {
    background: #26a69a none repeat scroll 0 0; 
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
.ck-button label:hover{
    background: #7dcac2 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color:#ffffff;  
}
.ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    /*top:-2000px;*/
}
.ck-button label input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
label.selected{
    background: #7dcac2 none repeat scroll 0 0;
      color:#ffffff;    
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.ck-button label').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected');    
});

$('.ck-button label').on('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: How about `.toggleClass()`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it does not work - https://jsfiddle.net/zdwjnLvL/1/

Comment: Not sure why am I downvoted .. Would appreciate a good genuine reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to replicate checkbox behaviour, I would probably use something like that:

```js
$('.ck-button input').on('change', function() {
  $(this.parentNode).toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
});
```

```css
.customCheckboxBtns {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.ck-button {
  margin-right: 0.375rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #26a69a;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  color: #999999;
}

.ck-button:hover {
  background: #7dcac2;
  border: 1px solid #26a69a;
  color: #26a69a;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.ck-button label {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  background: #26a69a;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.ck-button label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ck-button input:checked {
  background: #26a69a none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.ck-button label:hover {
  background: #7dcac2 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  /*top:-2000px;*/
}

.ck-button label input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label.selected {
  background: #7dcac2 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customCheckboxBtns">
  <div class="ck-button">
    <label>
      <input name="column-2" type="checkbox">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ck-button">
    <label class="selected">
      <input checked="checked" name="column-3" type="checkbox">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ck-button">
    <label>
      <input name="column-4" type="checkbox">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ck-button">
    <label>
      <input name="column-5" type="checkbox">4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="ck-button">
    <label>
      <input name="column-6" type="checkbox">5</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/zdwjnLvL/15/

Comment: Please put relevant code when you have working fiddle link. If not then at least hide the snippet.

Comment: @Rajesh Please motivate your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @VisioN .. It works fine on my environment .. +1 as well as accepted the answer

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
 $('.ck-button label').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass("selected"); 
 });`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/YvCil/zdwjnLvL/5/

Although this will not check the checkbox. When you have the click handler on the label it will fire for both the label and checkbox. See [Jquery click event triggers twice when clicked on html label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185265/jquery-click-event-triggers-twice-when-clicked-on-html-label)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts +1 .. @VisioN's answered worked on my environment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the click handler is fired twice when you click a label.
When you click the label, it triggers the click handler, but it also send a click to the associated input checkbox. That click bubbles up to it's containing elements, the label, causing the click handler to fire again.

You may want to listen to the `click` or `change` event on your `input` checkboxes, in stead of the label. This is also good for accessability, as it will still change your input value, and allow users to do so using the keyboard.

**Javascript excerpt**

```
$('.ck-button input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

**Sample**

```js
$('.ck-button input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.customCheckboxBtns {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

.ck-button {
  margin-right: 0.375rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #26a69a;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  color: #999999;
}

.ck-button:hover {
  background: #7dcac2;
  border: 1px solid #26a69a;
  color: #26a69a;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.ck-button label {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  background: #26a69a;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.ck-button label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ck-button input:checked {
  background: #26a69a none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.ck-button label:hover {
  background: #7dcac2 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ck-button label input {
  position: absolute;
  /*top:-2000px;*/
}

.ck-button label input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

label.selected {
  background: #7dcac2 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="customCheckboxBtns">
  <div class="ck-button"><label><input checked="checked" name="column-2" type="checkbox">1</label></div>
  <div class="ck-button"><label class="selected"><input checked="checked" name="column-3" type="checkbox">2</label></div>
  <div class="ck-button"><label><input checked="checked" name="column-4" type="checkbox">3</label></div>
  <div class="ck-button"><label><input checked="checked" name="column-5" type="checkbox">4</label></div>
  <div class="ck-button"><label><input checked="checked" name="column-6" type="checkbox">5</label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts +1 .. @VisioN's answered worked on my environment.