# Javascript click event triggers twice

Tags: javascript, html

In the following snippet, why does `divClicked()` trigger **twice** when the `<label>` is clicked, but only **once** when `<input>` is clicked?

```js
function divClicked(_index) {
  console.log("div click event");
}

function inputClicked(_index) {
  console.log("input click event");
}
```

```html
<div class="option" onclick="divClicked(1)">
  <input id="1_1" name="group_1" type="radio" value="1" onclick="inputClicked(1)" />
  <label for="1_1">label</label>
</div>
```

**Note:** I want to know **why** this happens, not a "quick fix" like: *put onclick() on label*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery click event triggers twice when clicked on html label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185265/jquery-click-event-triggers-twice-when-clicked-on-html-label)

Comment: @NishanthMatha Not sure how this is a dup of that because no where in that question are events attached to the containing div.

Comment: @NishanthMatha How is present Question a duplicate of linked Question?

Comment: @Zze @guest271314 not having a `div` or exact wordings in question doesn't make it unique. You see the explanation here: `And depending if you click on checkbox or the label, the callback for $('#test label') is called once or twice because the input element is part of the label and is one union and therefor also received the event if the label is click`

Comment: @NishanthMatha But the div event handler is executing twice, not the input handler

Comment: @NishanthMatha What @Andrew Li stated... the `inputClicked()` is only triggered once - maybe you should look at my example and question properly.

Comment: @NishanthMatha How does that explain why `divClicked` is called twice at present Question at `click` at `label` element?

Comment: @guest271314 Was that comment for me or @NishanthMatha? If it was for me, then I'm afraid i'm not certain what you're asking me?

Comment: @Zze Corrected addressee of comment

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens because of what the HTML spec describes at [4.10.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element):

> For example, on platforms where clicking a checkbox label checks the
>   checkbox, clicking the `label` in the following snippet could trigger
>   the user agent to **run synthetic click activation steps** on the `input`
>   element, as if the element itself had been triggered by the user:
>
> ```
> <label><input type=checkbox name=lost> Lost</label>
> ```
>
> On other platforms, the behavior might be just to focus the control,
>   or do nothing.

This means that when a `<label>` is clicked, the browser creates a second "synthetic" click event on the associated `<input>` element, in order to toggle its state.

The reason `divClicked` is triggered twice, is because the first event which comes from the `<label>` bubbles up to the `<div>`, and also the second, synthetic click event bubbles up to the `<div>`.

Comment: For what it's worth, my answer consisted of this part of the spec and a bit more and explained the bubbling, step by step. Since this answer would've been shorter and more concise, it's better.

Comment: Add         e.preventDefault();  at last line , in my case , its fixed

Answer (score 0):

This is usually be cause of the `bubbling` principle of `click` event:

> When an event happens on an element, it runs on it, its associated elements,its parent and other ancestors.

Now, The relation is when you click on `label` there a are two events which bubbles up here:

**1) Click on div (which you expect)**

**2) Click on input (which is also expected)**

> **2.1) When click on `input` is triggered then a click on `div` is also triggered again here**

You can confirm this behavior by using `event.bubbles` prop.

***EDIT:***

The reason for the connection between `label` and `input`: (I know this is absolutely not required, as it's present all over the place yet)

> A `<label>` can be associated with a control either by placing the control `element inside the <label>` element, `or by using the for` attribute. Such a control is called the labeled control of the label element. One input can be associated with multiple labels.

Taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Which means placing `for` on label referencing `id` of an input element will stimulate the behavior as if the element is inside the `label`. This would `bubble` a event on `input` onto `label` like any event on `child` to `parent`

Comment: You've only described a single event, bubbling up through multiple elements. Bubbling doesn't create multiple events, it just describes the behavior of how one event triggers handlers on all ancestors.

Comment: @4castle I guess The more important part is `2.1` which is highlighted! the concept of event bubbling is just to tell that `click` on label or `click` on input would trigger a click on `div`...then comes the actual reason which is `2.1`

Comment: The part that's missing from your answer is: Why does clicking on the label produce a second, separate event on the input element? You've described bubbling, but not explained how the `<input>` handler is toggled by clicking on the label, even though the `<input>` isn't an ancestor of the `<label>`.

Comment: @4castle that's all over the internet..(even in my comment to OP)! Yet if you think that's what missing refer to my edit!!

Comment: Your edit still doesn't describe why clicking on the label would trigger a click on the `<input>`. Events don't bubble downwards to child elements or sibling elements, only to ancestor elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139715/discussion-between-4castle-and-nishanth-matha).