# Click event handler on a div with label get triggered twice

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('call');
})
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <p>
      Hello
    </p>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

I have the following markup:

```
<div>
  <label>
    <p>
      Hello
    </p>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Why when I register an event listener on the **div** element it called it twice?

```
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('call');
})
```

Comment: Can you please create a snippet to show the problem. I don't think this is ur complete code

Comment: It's likely to be caused by the checkbox.

Comment: Is that the only `div` within the scope of `document.querySelector()`?

Comment: Added a live example

Comment: I think the label and the checkbox propagate a click event each, both which is caught by the listener. I don't have a concrete answer however.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript click event triggers twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174996/javascript-click-event-triggers-twice)

Comment: @Tanner Yes. thanks!