# How to change between 2 background colors using JavaScript with one button

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color, event-listener

I posted a question similar to this and the solution people provided worked, but it only worked when I comment out all my other CSS code. For some reason, the CSS is interfering with the JavaScript function to work properly. I want to change the background color to black when I click the button, but I want to change it back to white when I click on it again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Light Switch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="light.css" />
</head>

<body id="body">
  <div id="click">
    <label id="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
<script src="light.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
#switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 4px;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
   background-color: #1583ea;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```
function start() {
  var click = document.getElementById("switch");
  click.addEventListener("click", toggle);
};

function toggle() {
  var color = document.getElementById("body");
  var backColor = color.style.backgroundColor;
  color.style.backgroundColor = backColor === "black" ? "white" : "black";
};


start();
```

Comment: Do a `console.log(backColor)` and make sure it is the value you were looking for. My guess is it's not. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function was triggering twice due to the event listener on the switch div as opposed to the slider itself. I refactored your code a bit.

```js
function start() {
  var toggleSwitch = document.getElementById("slider");
  toggleSwitch.addEventListener("click", toggle);
};

function toggle() {
  var backColor = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = backColor === "black" ? "white" : "black";
};


start();
```

```css
#switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 4px;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
   background-color: #1583ea;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Light Switch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="light.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <label id="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <span id="slider" class="slider"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
<script src="light.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: interesting... now i'm curious, why the event is triggering twice when you put it on the _label_ tag?

Comment: @JonKoala

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element

Comment: @blastitall ty! My first thought was event bubbling too, but it seems to be something different, check this answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17185362/1269898

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `.toggle`, specifically, `classList.toggle("my-black");`

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var body = document.body;
button.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
   body.classList.toggle("my-black");
});
```

```css
.my-black{
 background:#424242;
}
html,body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<button>asdfasdf</button>
```

Comment: Ive already tried using the classList.toggle property, and I have the same problem. it works when I dont apply my other CSS code

Comment: use browser develop tools inspector and right click over your background and click 'inspect' then check where the color is coming from (which CSS is overriding)