# Bind an event to some element without binding to it's child - JQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I have some div called mydiv. I have a click event attached to it. Inside of the div I have a link. I want the event not to be triggered after clicking on the link. Smth like

```
$(document).on('click', '#mydiv a', function(){
    // How to disable parent's event here?
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728252/jquery-stoppropagation-bubble-down

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that the click handler bound to the `div` will trigger first because the delegated event will only fire once the event has propagated right up to the `document`.

In your `#mydiv` click handler, check that the `event.target === this` before executing any code, that way, it'll only fire when the `div` has been clicked.

Something like this:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
      alert('div click fired!'); 
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#mydiv a', function(e) {
   alert('anchor click fired!'); 
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7U8cJ/5/)

---

**Edit** If the only reason you're attaching an event handler to the `anchor` is to prevent triggering the click handler on the `div`, just check if the target is not an `anchor` in the `div` click handler before doing anything else:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
        return;
    }
    alert('div click fired!'); 
});
```

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7U8cJ/9/)

Comment: The problem is that the event attached to the parent was attached by Galleria plugin and I don't know how was it attached...

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
$(document).on('click', '#mydiv a', function(e){
    // How to disable parent's event here?
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: From jQuery's docs, am I misunderstanding? "Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event."

Comment: It would work if the event hadn't been delegated. The event handler is attached to the document, so it only fires once it has reached the document, by which time the click handler on the `div` has already fired

Comment: You can also use single JQuery for click event on div as well as to prevent click event on its child

Answer (score 0):

Try this so you can use single JQuery

**HTML**

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span> Hello, How are you? </span>
    <a id="alink" href="#"> Click ME </a>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click', '#mydiv', function(event){
   alert("You clicked on Div Span");
 }).children().find("#alink").click(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shijukbabu/Hgvq5/2/)