# html div onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have one html div on my jsp page, on that i have put one anchor tag, please find code below for that,

```
<div class="expandable-panel-heading">
     <h2>
         <a id="ancherComplaint" href="#addComplaint" 
                            onclick="markActiveLink(this);">ABC</a>
     </h2>
</div>
```

js code

```
$('.expandable-panel-heading:not(#ancherComplaint)').click(function () {
     alert('123');
 });

function markActiveLink(el) {   
    alert($(el).attr("id"));
}
```

here I when I click on **div** I got alert with `123` message, its fine but when I click on **ABC** I want message I want to call `markActiveLink` method.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVrNc/2/)

what is wrong with my code? please help me out.

Comment: You need to read up on event bubbling and for sure remove inline event handling if you have jQuery anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery stopPropagation bubble down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728252/jquery-stoppropagation-bubble-down)

Comment: You can keep on using this just what you need is to place the method before the onclick is used. update fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/JVrNc/7/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem was that clicking the anchor still triggered a click in your `<div>`. That's called "[event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)".

In fact, there are multiple solutions:

- Checking in the DIV click event handler whether the actual target element was the anchor
  [→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVrNc/3/)

  ```
  $('.expandable-panel-heading').click(function (evt) {
      if (evt.target.tagName != "A") {
          alert('123');
      }

      // Also possible if conditions:
      // - evt.target.id != "ancherComplaint"
      // - !$(evt.target).is("#ancherComplaint")
  });

  $("#ancherComplaint").click(function () {
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
  ```
- Stopping the event propagation from the anchor click listener
  [→ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVrNc/5/)

  ```
  $("#ancherComplaint").click(function (evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });
  ```

---

As you may have noticed, I have removed the following selector part from my examples:

```
:not(#ancherComplaint)
```

This was unnecessary because there is no element with the class `.expandable-panel-heading` which also have `#ancherComplaint` as its ID.

I assume that you wanted to suppress the event for the anchor. That cannot work in that manner because both selectors (yours and mine) select the exact same DIV. The selector has no influence on the listener when it is called; it only sets the list of elements to which the listeners should be registered. Since this list is the same in both versions, there exists no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.expandable-panel-heading:not(#ancherComplaint)').click(function () {
    alert('123');
});

$('#ancherComplaint').click(function (event) {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
    event.stopPropagation()
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PDVTq/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
$('.expandable-panel-heading').click(function (e) {
        if(e.target.nodeName == 'A'){
            markActiveLink(e.target)
            return; 
        }else{
            alert('123');
        }
 });

function markActiveLink(el) {   
    alert($(el).attr("id"));
}
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JVrNc/4/

Answer (score 2):

Change your jQuery code with this. It will alert the id of the a.

```
$('.expandable-panel-heading:not(#ancherComplaint)').click(function () {
markActiveLink();    
     alert('123');
 });

function markActiveLink(el) {   
var el = $('a').attr("id")
    alert(el);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f57Rj/1/)

Comment: Clicking anywhere in the DIV would result in two alerts() being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read up on event bubbling and for sure remove inline event handling if you have jQuery anyway

Test the click on the div and examine the target

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kDnRy/)

```
$(".expandable-panel-heading").on("click",function (e) {
    if (e.target.id =="ancherComplaint") { // or test the tag
        e.preventDefault(); // or e.stopPropagation()
        markActiveLink(e.target);
    }    
    else alert('123');
});
function markActiveLink(el) {   
    alert(el.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have used `stopPropagation` like this:

```
$('.expandable-panel-heading:not(#ancherComplaint)').click(function () {
     alert('123');
 });

$('#ancherComplaint').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('hiiiiiiiiii');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this example, the onclick is still called from your HTML, and event bubbling is stopped.

```
<div class="expandable-panel-heading">
<h2>
  <a id="ancherComplaint" href="#addComplaint" onclick="markActiveLink(this);event.stopPropagation();">ABC</a>
</h2>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NXML7/1/

Answer (score 0):

put your jquery function inside ready function for call click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#ancherComplaint").click(function () {
     alert($(this).attr("id"));
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

when click on div alert key

```
   $(document).delegate(".searchbtn", "click", function() {
        var key=$.trim($('#txtkey').val());
        alert(key);
        });
```