# jQuery and DataTables with not() selector

Tags: jquery, datatables

In the following code, how can I make it so clicking the checkbox or input field doesn't toggle the row selection? I tried using the not() selector as in:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr:not(input)', function () ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kevmor/7txDz/

Comment: Thanks that works but now I realized I have another problem, I'm using a checkbox per row as a 'select all' checkboxes for the row. If I stop the bubble up is there a way I can still do the select all (checkboxes)?

Comment: The selector `'tr:not(input)'` selects all `<tr>` elements which are also not `<input>` elements. Really, the only way to "select a tr excluding specific descendants" is to do the stopPropagation approach @DylanHayes shows below, I believe.  I wanted to do exactly what you're describing, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Event Bubbling.

[jQuery stopPropagation bubble down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728252/jquery-stoppropagation-bubble-down)

Use:

```
$('input').on('click', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use `e.stopPropagation()` on inputs:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', ':input', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); // stops the event to bubble up to the dom tree
}).on('click', 'tr', function () ...
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7txDz/1/)

---

`:input` in jQuery selects all the form elements including **checkboxes, radios, textareas, selects etc**.