# Jquery click, how to avoid it from working in inside elements?

Tags: jquery, click

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

I have a div (a) which needs a jquery click event. I don't want the event to happen when clicking in b (which is nested). Is it possible to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I reckon API you are looking for is : `.stoppropagation` - http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

**Please note** for `bubble down` : [jQuery stopPropagation bubble down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728252/jquery-stoppropagation-bubble-down)

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/3AW29/

**Sample code**

```
$( "#a" ).click(function( event ) {
event.stopPropagation();
// Do something
});
```

**Bubble Down** Sample

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#a").click(function (event) {
         event.stopPropagation();
         if ($(event.target).prop('id') == 'a') 
             alert('t' + $(event.target).prop('id'));
         // Do something
     });
 });
```