# Jquery closing on parent click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a window to close only when `pop_up` is clicked (as opposed to clicking div contents). E.g. clicking the background layer hides the div. In the code below I don't want it to close `#pop_up` when  clicking the div contents bot only on "pop_up".

How can I do this?

```js
$("#pop_up").click(function() {
    $("#pop_up").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pop_up">
  <div id="pop_up_content">
    <h1> world </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728252/jquery-stoppropagation-bubble-down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `event` argument of the click, and see if the click is inside another element (or it is the element itself)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32mz2x3x/1/

```
$("#pop_up").click(function(event) {
      if ($(event.target).parents().andSelf().is('#pop_up_content')) {
        return 
    }
    $("#pop_up").hide();
});
```

I have used `parents` to check if where you click is inside `pop_up_content` element, and I used `andSelf` because maybe you click on `#pop_up_content` (and not inside it)

---

**More info:**

- [jQuery `andSelf` function](https://api.jquery.com/andself/)
- [jQuery `is` function](http://api.jquery.com/is/)
- [jQuery `parents` function](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)
- [jQuery `event` object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

Comment: Yep thats the one, I was trying to do something like this earlier on and now I see where I've failed! Thanks mate! Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

What you are experiencing is the bubbling and capturing behaviour of events. 
Check this answer [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) .

The simples approach would be to attach a onClick to the child and stop the bubbling.

```
$("#pop_up_content").click(function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault()
   ev.stopImmediatePropagation() // best to use to stop other event listeners from being called
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use the form that allows a filter selector, combined with `:not()`:

```
$("#pop_up").on('click', ':not(#pop_up_content)', function (e) {
    $("#pop_up").hide();
});
```

Comment: For some reason its working vice-versa for me, like if u click pop_up_content it will close the pop_up and when you click pop_up it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 1):

[JSBin: http://jsbin.com/hoyizos/edit?html,css,js,output](http://jsbin.com/hoyizos/edit?html,css,js,output)

```js
$("#pop_up").click(function(e) { 
    if ($(event.target).is($("#pop_up"))){   
        $("#pop_up").hide();  
    }     
});
```

```css
h1{
  margin:50px 50px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline;
}

#pop_up_content{
  background-color:yellow;
}

#pop_up{
  margin:10px;

  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pop_up">
            <div id="pop_up_content">pop_up_content
                <h1> world </h1>
            </div>
I am the pop_up!
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't cancel event bubbling!: [The Dangers of Stopping Event Propagation](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/), 
use it only if there is no other way.

Don't use `andSelf()` if you plan to use jQuery 3.x, [because it is deprecated since v1.8 and will be removed in jQuery v3](https://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).

> Note: This function has been deprecated and is now an alias for
>   .addBack(), which should be used with jQuery 1.8 and later.

If you use jQuery 1.8 < use `addBack` instead.